# PHP Rector does not work at all because of "Cannot rename"

Tags: php, permissions, rector

I use [Rector](https://getrector.com/) to automatically refactor a codebase. I try to replace the outdated functions like `utf8_decode()` and `utf8_encode()` with custom user-defined functions. The `rector.php` looks like this:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Rector\Config\RectorConfig;
use Utils\Rector\ReplaceUTF8Functions;

return static function (RectorConfig $rectorConfig): void {
    $rectorConfig->paths([
        __DIR__ . \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'service.php'
    ]);
    $rectorConfig->rule(ReplaceUTF8Functions::class);;
};
```

And the `ReplaceUTF8Functions` looks like this:

```php
<?php
namespace Utils\Rector;

use PhpParser\Node;
use PhpParser\Node\Name;
use PhpParser\Node\Expr\FuncCall;
use Rector\Rector\AbstractRector;
use Symplify\RuleDocGenerator\ValueObject\CodeSample\CodeSample;
use Symplify\RuleDocGenerator\ValueObject\RuleDefinition;
use function array_key_exists;

final class ReplaceUTF8Functions extends AbstractRector {

    private const REPLACEMENT = [
        'utf8_decode' => 'utf8ToLatin1',
        'utf8_encode' => 'latin1ToUtf8'
    ];

    public function getNodeTypes(): array {
        return [
            FuncCall::class
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param FuncCall $node
     * @return null|Node
     */
    public function refactor(Node $node): ?Node {
        $name = $this->getName($node->name);
        if (!array_key_exists($name, self::REPLACEMENT))
            return null;
        $node->name = new Name(self::REPLACEMENT[$name]);
        return $node;
    }

    public function getRuleDefinition(): RuleDefinition {
        return new RuleDefinition('Replace the utf8_* functions with custom counterparts', [
                new CodeSample(
                    'utf8_decode(\'string\');',
                    'utf8ToLatin1(\'string\');'
                )
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

But once I try to run it:

```
vendor\bin\rector process
```

It gives an error:

```
                                    cts\trunk\service.php" file, due to:
         "System error: "Cannot rename "C:\Projects\trunk\ser8FA1.tmp" to
         "C:\Projects\trunk\service.php":
         rename(C:\Projects\trunk\ser8FA1.tmp,C:\Projects\trunk\service.php): Zugriff verweigert (code:

         Run Rector with "--debug" option and post the report here: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/new". On line: 286

Script rector handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 1
```

Firstly, the error message is not complete at all. It's trimmed. I ran it in the Windows Command Prompt, in the ConEmu - it does not get better. Moreover - I tried to give all the permissions to the current user on the file I want to process - nothing. I've tried to run the command as follows - `vendor\bin\rector process`. I tried to run it as administrator. Have you encountered the same error?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Composer itself?

Comment: Whats the output for: vendor\bin\rector process --debug

Comment: @NicoHaase No, I don't think the problem is related to Composer anyhow. But the trimming is definetely a Composer's problem, because I constantly see how Composer trims output

Comment: @talha2k the output is:
```
#0
 C:\Projects\trunk\vendor\rector\rector\vendor\symfony\filesystem\Filesystem.p
 hp(596):
 RectorPrefix202401\Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->rename('C:\\Projects\\t
 ii...', 'C:\\Projects\\tru...', true)
 #1
```
It's trimmed and too large to paste as a comment

Comment: Is trimming the core problem here? Why not care about thie problem itself?

Comment: Are there no enabled log files which you can tail?

Comment: @NicoHaase the trimming is not the problem. The problem is that Rector cannot overwrite a file

Comment: @talha2k Nope. The error log file (it's php-8.2.11_errors.log in my case) is empty. Rector outputs everything into console. I tried to search for Composer log files (if any) but it seems like Composer does not have its own log files

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If running Rector without Composer yields the same output, remove all Composer stuff from the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked [the same](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/8432) on the GitHub page and the developers fixed the issue